# Print multiple report with different data according to the condition at the same time using crystal sap report in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I want to print multiple report according to the print status with different data at the same time using crystal report in c#.net. For ex : In my task there is 5 kinds of print status i.e.

1. Original
2. Duplicate
3. Triplicate
4. Choblicate
5. All

this 5 status was in checkbox option. Now, if any one person has select the original as well as duplicate option and clicking the button at that time the selected checkbox status report want to be shown i.e. original as well as duplicate report with different status was been shown.

Different Status means : in original report it shows the original status while in duplicate report it shows the duplicate status.

same as if any other person has check the all option at that time whole report pages want be shown at the same time with different status.

I can do this for the any one report status only at the time but nothing get idea about the multiple status.

Here is my code for any one of the report status.

```
private void btn_previewdocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string mtmptbl = "TmpRetailInvoicePrint";
                RetailInvoicePrint frm = new RetailInvoicePrint();
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                timer1.Enabled = true;

                ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cn.ConnectionString);
                ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

                string qryPreviewDocument = " SELECT distinct Client.clientname as ClientName, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.invoiceno as InvoiceNo, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.pono as PoNO, RetailInvoice.issuedate as IssueDate, RetailInvoice.duedate as DueDate, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.discount as Discount, RetailInvoice.shipping as Shipping, RetailInvoice.tax as Tax, RetailInvoice.vat as Vat, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.sese as Sese, RetailInvoice.paymenttype as PaymentType, RetailInvoice.chequeno as Chequeno, RetailInvoice.totalamt as TotalAmt, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoice.description as Description, RetailInvoice.paymentpaid as PaymentPaid, RetailInvoice.subtotal as Subtotal, " + System.Environment.NewLine;

                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoicePayment.productid as ProductName, RetailInvoicePayment.uom as Uom, " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " RetailInvoicePayment.quantity as Quantity, RetailInvoicePayment.price as Price " + System.Environment.NewLine;

                qryPreviewDocument += " into " + mtmptbl + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;

                qryPreviewDocument += " from tbl_retailinvoice RetailInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_retailinvoicepayment RetailInvoicePayment " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " ON RetailInvoice.invoiceno = RetailInvoicePayment.invoiceno " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_clientdetail Client ON RetailInvoice.clientid = Client.clientid " + System.Environment.NewLine;

                qryPreviewDocument += " where RetailInvoice.BranchID = " + lbl_branchid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoice.YearID = " + lbl_yearid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoice.invoiceno = " + txt_invoice.Text + "";

                qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoicePayment.BranchID = " + lbl_branchid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoicePayment.YearID = " + lbl_yearid.Text + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                qryPreviewDocument += " and RetailInvoicePayment.invoiceno = " + txt_invoice.Text + "";

                string SQL = "select upper(name) as TABLE_NAME FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' and name = '" + mtmptbl + "' order by name";
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string qrydrop = "drop table " + mtmptbl + "";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrydrop, cn);
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                }

                MyCommand = new SqlCommand(qryPreviewDocument, cn);
                MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cn.Open();
                MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

                string crReportPath = Application.StartupPath.Replace("bin\\Debug", "") + "\\Print";

                cryRpt.Load(crReportPath + "\\RptRetailInvoice.rpt");

                builder.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["con"];
                string dbName = builder.InitialCatalog;
                string dbDataSource = builder.DataSource;
                string userID = builder.UserID;
                string pass = builder.Password;

                crConnectionInfo.ServerName = dbDataSource;
                crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = dbName;
                crConnectionInfo.UserID = userID;
                crConnectionInfo.Password = pass;

                Tables Crtables;
                Crtables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;

                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in Crtables)
                {
                    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                }

                frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
                frm.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

                Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                frm.Show();
                btn_reset.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

This code I have done under the btn_previewdocument click event. So when this event occur at that time report will be generated.

Advance In Thanks.

Comment: I didnt see anything in your code that changed the report from original to dup, trip etc..

Comment: Yah. Because this code is for the print the one report and for multiple report I am confuse that where the multiple code will excute.

Comment: What do you mean print? in printer itself or just show the multiple report as your screen?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to spot (and failed) the area in your report that denoted it as "original", "duplicate" etc, in short, my advice would be take most of that and refactor it into a "printreport" method, with a variable, that denotes that status, then in your event, you would then code something like the following pseudo code

```
if selected_original then printreport("original")
if selected_duplicate then printreport("dupliate")
...
if selected_all then 
   printreport("original")
 & printreport("dupliate")
 & ...
```

that string of course can be altered, but if necessary used within the report to designate its status (as I didnt see how you're doing that in your code, Im going to have to leave that to you)

Comment: in my code this line load the crystal "reportcryRpt.Load(crReportPath + "\\RptRetailInvoice.rpt");". So how I can implement load multiple report in such a line.

Comment: you dont, you make repeated calls to the same thing..... or print x copies